# Generate SAS code using input specifications

Tags: excel, vba, automation, sas

We have a set of predefined macros, developed in SAS, which are used for generating tables, listing and figures using SAS datasets. My requirement is specifically for automating SAS code generation for tables. There are some fixed numbers of templates available for the tables to be generated. Also, a SAS programs are available to generate each table output. Whenever a table from these templates needs to be generated, the related SAS program needs to be modified to generate the required output.

To avoid the redundacy of writing SAS programs each time separately to generate the fixed kind of output, I want to create a tool which will generate a SAS code. This code will serve as a source to generate tables.

I have prepared an excel workbook with all required details for constructing program (like various parameters and their values e.g. title, footnote, source dataset, group by row/column). A simple user form created in Excel is used to display and configure these parameters.

The question is now - how to generate SAS statements using Excel VBA? and How to connect with SAS using Excel VBA to execute SAS programs?

If you have done anything like this before or if you have any ideas for this type of problem statement, could you please share them here. Any help is really appreciable.

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest to try the SAS institute excel forum. Another suggestion would be to look in the SAS add-in object library within VBA. The only VBA-integration i have managed is to update SAS tables :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you unsure of how to generate a text file from VBA? If you know how to do that, generating SAS code shouldn't be a problem. However, I have worked on systems like this in the past and I would do the SAS code generation in SAS as well; that just seems like a better separation of responsibilities within the system. Write a SAS program that reads the Excel sheet, generates suitable SAS code to create the table, and then runs the SAS code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Chris. To clarify more about my question - I am looking for solution to generate SAS code through VBA. I am interested to see if someone has already done this kind of stuff in more logical manner. The way I am doing as of now is in very simple manner by writing my own logical rules to generate the intended code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't involve VBA. I would write a SAS program to read the requirements, generate the tables and push them back to a new Excel program. If you want to drive this from an Excel program entirely, I would recommend the SAS Add-In for Excel instead of VBA code, though you could trigger it via VBA. Chris Hemidinger is the SAS expert in these types of issues and he does post on communities.sas.com as another user indicated you should post there (in comments).

It's a trivial process to create empty tables, but reporting tables often have a very specific layout so you may be able to generalize this process further. For example, I have a macro that creates my standard Table 1 (table of characteristics) for a data set, where I just need to specify the input variables by type (continuous, categorical, binary) and the output is generated and can be pushed to excel via ODS EXCEL. I also use PROC REPORT to format it, because I'll shade the rows alternately for different variables so that's easier to read/display.

```
/*
This macro creates a table of charateristics for the variables listed.  
It handles categorical, binary and continuous variables and produces and output dataset that can be further customized. No statistical information is
included in this analysis
*/

/*Parameters to be set:
dsetin - name of dataset to be analyzed
cont = macro variable list of variable names, ie cont=age weight height
cat=list of categorical variables ie cat=sex grade
bin=binary variables, such as smoking now, smoking ever
dsetout=name of output dataset
Run example at the end for a sample output dataset call sample_table_char in the work directory
*/


*options mprint symbolgen;
%macro table_char(dsetin, cont, cat, bin, dsetout);


*delete old dataset;

proc datasets nodetails nolist;
    delete &dsetout;
quit;

/****************************************************************
Handle Categorical Variables
****************************************************************/

*loop through variable list;
%let i=1;
%do %while (%scan(&cat, &i, " ") ^=%str());
%let var=%scan(&cat, &i, " ");  

*Get format for variable;
data _null_;
 set &dsetin;
 call symput("var_fmt", vformat(&var));
run;



proc freq data=&dsetin noprint;
    table &var/missing out=tab_var;
run;



data temp1;
    length categorical $200.; format categorical $200.;
    length value $200.; format value $200.;

    set tab_var;
    percent=percent/100;
    categorical=put(&var., &var_fmt.);
    if _n_=1 then do;
        value=put(count, 8.)||"("||compress(put(percent, percent8.1))||")";
        order=2;
        output;
        order=1;
        value='';
        categorical=propcase(vlabel(&var.));
        output;
    end;
    else do;
        order=2;
        value=put(count, 8.)||"("||compress(put(percent, percent8.1))||")";
        output;

    end;

    keep categorical value order;
run;

proc sort data=temp1 out=temp2 (drop=order); by order categorical; run;


proc append base=&dsetout data=temp2;
run;

*clean up;

proc datasets nodetails nolist;
    delete tab_var temp1 temp2;
run; quit;

*Increment counter;
%let i=%eval(&i+1);
%end; *Categorical;

/****************************************************************
Handle Continuous Variables
****************************************************************/

%let i=1;
%do %while (%scan(&cont, &i, " ") ^=%str());
%let var=%scan(&cont, &i, " "); 



proc means data=&dsetin (rename=&var=vn) noprint;
var vn;
output out=table_var n= nmiss= mean= min= max= std= median= p25= p75= p90=/autoname;
run;

*get label of variable for clean reporting;
data _null_;
 set &dsetin;
 call symput("var_label", vlabel(&var));
run;




data temp1;
    length categorical $200.; format categorical $200.;
    format value $200.; length value $200.;

    set table_var;

    categorical="&var_label.";
    value=.;
    output;

    categorical='Count(Missing)';
    value=put(vn_n, 5.)||"("||compress(put(vn_nmiss, 5.))||")";
    output;

    categorical='Mean (SD)';
    value=put(vn_mean, 8.1)||"("||compress(put(vn_stddev, 8.1))||")";
    output;

    categorical='Median (IQR)';
    value=put(vn_median, 8.1)||"("||compress(put(vn_p25, 8.1))||" - "||compress(put(vn_p75, 8.1))||")";
    output;

    categorical='Range';
    value=put(vn_min, 8.1)||" - "||compress(put(vn_max, 8.1));
    output;

    categorical='90th Percentile';
    value=put(vn_p90, 8.1);
    output;



    keep categorical value;
run;


proc append base=&dsetout data=temp1;
run;

*clean up;

proc datasets nodetails nolist;
    delete table_var temp1;
run; quit;

*Increment counter;
%let i=%eval(&i+1);
%end; *Continuous;

/*****************************************************************
Handle Binary Variables (only report 1s)
*****************************************************************/

%let i=1;
%do %while (%scan(&bin, &i, " ") ^=%str());
%let var=%scan(&bin, &i, " ");  



proc freq data=&dsetin noprint;
    table &var/missing out=tab_var;
run;

data tab_var;
    set tab_var;
    where &var=1;
run;

data temp1;
    length categorical $200.; format categorical $200.;
    length value $200.; format value $200.;

    set tab_var;
    percent=percent/100;
    if _n_=1 then do;
        value=put(count, 8.)||"("||compress(put(percent, percent8.1))||")";
        order=1;
        categorical=propcase(vlabel(&var.));
        output;
    end;
    keep categorical value;
run;




proc append base=&dsetout data=temp1;
run;

*clean up;

proc datasets nodetails nolist;
    delete tab_var temp1;
run; quit;

*Increment counter;
%let i=%eval(&i+1);
%end;*Binary;


%mend table_char;


/* *Example of macro usage; */
/* data sample; */
/*  set sashelp.class; */
/*  female=ifn( sex='F',1,0); */
/* run; */
/*  */
/*  */
/* %table_char(sample, height weight age, sex, female, sample_table_char); */
```

Comment: Thanks Reeza for providing pointers to look for probable solution.